# Add SonarQube to jenkins job pipeline failed

Tags: jenkins, groovy, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

At the moment we try to add SonarQube analyzing  to our jenkins job pipeline. But every time the build job failed with the message: `"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: **No such DSL method withSonarQubeEnv".` We have reinstall all plugins and configurations. Nothing help.
So maybe someone of you can help us.

**What we have done:**

Do all  steps of this tutorial from sonarqube: [Analyzing with SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins)

- Install SonarQube Plugin 2.5
- Add and configure SonarQube under **Manage Jenkins > Configure System**
- Add  SonarQube Scanner under  **Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration**
- Add this code after the checkout of our project to the groovy file for the pipeline:

  ```
  stage('SonarQube analysis')
  // requires SonarQube Scanner 2.8+
  def scannerHome = tool 'SonarQube Scanner 2.8';
  withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube 5.6.4') {
    sh "${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner"
  }
  ```

Current Versions of our tools

- Our Jenkins has the version 2.2
- Our SonarQube Server has the version 5.6.4

The SonarQube Server run fine. We can analyzing our code over a local scanner.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to test with sonarqube 2.5 plugin but keep getting a different serialization error but have tested the below code which works fine and is without "withSonarQubeEnv" just in case you are looking for alternative:

```
stage('SonarQube analysis')
// requires SonarQube Scanner 2.8+
def scannerHome = tool 'SonarQube Scanner 2.8';
sh "${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner"
```

PS: I'll try to test with sonarqube 2.5 plugin and let you know if I find something.

Comment: Thank you for your time. But when i run your code, the scanner not use the SonarQube Configurations. It doesn't use our server, he try to connect to localhost..: `SonarQube server [http://localhost:9000] can not be reached`  Load the configuration from: 
 `file: /home/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/SonarQube_Scanner_Prod/conf/sonar-scanner.properties`

Comment: I have solve my problem. Use your code now with the -Dsonar.host.url= parameter. Thank you very much