# Show SonarQube result link on Jenkins Job page

Tags: jenkins, groovy, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I use jenkins and sonar to analyze some projects. The sonar analyzing triggered over the groovy pipeline script with the following code:

`stage('SonarQube analysis')
    def scannerHome = tool 'SonarQube_Scanner_Prod';
    sh "${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner -e -Dsonar.host.url=... -Dsonar.projectKey=... -Dsonar.projectName=... -Dsonar.sources=... -Dsonar.projectVersion=..."`

This work fine. Now I want a link on the jenkins job page. To come to the sonar results on the server. After the sonar analysis run, the link is on the console. Can i add this link to the status page? Or add a link to the left menu? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

As far I know Once the job is complete, the plugin will detect that a SonarQube analysis was made during the build and display a badge and a widget on the job page with a link to the SonarQube dashboard as well as quality gate status.
Please refer [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins) and verify your configurations.

Comment: I try to run the analyze with this tutorial. But i have a problem with the withSonarQubeEnv. You can see on this topic [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879168/add-sonarqube-to-jenkins-job-pipeline-failed). With the code at the top the analyze run fine. But there are no displays on the job